# Clarification on setting up the bounds of integration for $U = \{ (x,y) | -1 \leq x-y \leq 1 , \qquad1 \leq xy \leq 2 \}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, area, solution-verification

I have a few challenges setting up the bounds of integration for the region 
$$U = \{(x,y) | -1 \leq x-y \leq 1 , \quad 1 \leq xy \leq 2 \}$$
My ultimate goal is to solve $$\iint_U x^2y + xy^2 dxdy = \iint_U f(x,y) dxdy$$

Here is a plot of the domain I have to consider:

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image: enter image description here][1]]

Since the region is symmetric, I decided to first focus on the first quadrant.
The domain is not simple, therefore I divided it into simple domains by introducing two new bounds $x=1$ and $y=1$  yielding three simple domains: ([Link to the interactive graph on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8cshs9eejc))

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image: enter image description here][3]]

Starting with the region below $y=1$ then the middle region, then the upper one, I came up with the following limits:

$$\int_{ y= \frac{\sqrt5 - 1}{2} }^1 \int_{\frac1y}^{y+1} \space f(x,y) \space dxdy + \int_{ x=1 }^2 \int_{1}^{\frac2x} \space f(x,y) \space dydx + \int_{ y=1 }^2 \int_{\frac1y}^{1} \space f(x,y) \space dxdy $$

Now, the order turned out different for each of the summands, which is making me doubt that my setup is correct. Also, it seems to me that the points on the lines $x=1$ and $y=1$ will be ... counted twice (?) since they border two different integrals if that makes sense. Thus, could anyone kindly clarify on this.

Comment: You'll have a much easier time if you use the change of variables $u = x - y$ and $v = xy$, which should straighten out the desired regions to look more like rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

Let's operat the substitution:
$$u:=x-y\\
v=xy$$
EDIT: the transformation of the region was wrong 
Then, the region $U^+:=U \cap \lbrace (x,y): x>0, y>0\rbrace$ becomes 
$$ \tilde{U}:=\big\lbrace(u,v): -1\le u\le1 , 1\le v \le 2 \big\rbrace$$

Then, the Jacobian is: 
$$J= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1\\
y & x
\end{pmatrix}$$
 which has determinant $ |J|=x+y$.
Then:

$$\iint_{U^+} x^2y + xy^2 dxdy =
\iint_{U^+} xy(x + y) dxdy
\iint_{\tilde{U}} xy\ (x + y) \frac{1}{x+y} dudv =\\
=\iint_{\tilde U} v\  dudv = \int_{1}^2\int_{-1}^1 v \ dudv = \int_{1}^2 2v \ dv =3$$

As @Gabrielek pointed out, the integral on the whole region is $0$, this is the velue on the upper right region $U^+$.

Comment: How did you calculate the partials in the Jacobian without an explicit expression for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$?

Comment: What I mean is, when calculating the Jacobian, you take the partial derivatives of the **old variables** with respect to the new ones. What you have done is the opposite.

Comment: Well, actually  i took the derivatives of the new w.r.t. the old one. Then I multiply for the inverse of the jacobian $\frac{1}{|J|}$. If the Jacobian you are talking about is called $I$ (old variable derivated w.r.t. the new one), then $|I|=\frac{1}{|J|}$

Comment: Got it. Now I'm trying to figure out why the other posted answer is $0$.

Comment: But you're right, and I agree that the integral is 0. I think 3 is the value only on the upper right region, that equals - the value on the bottom left.

Comment: It turns out that the answer is actually three over the whole region, not zero.

Comment: How can you say that?

Comment: The Jacobian has to have an absolute value. So it is $|x + y|$.

Comment: Of course! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly written your domain, and you can easily see that is symmetrical with respect to the reflection $$r = \begin{cases}
x \to -x \\
y \to -y
\end{cases}$$

Let's define $U_+$ the region of you domain in the first quadrant and $U_-$ the other. Observe that $f(x,y) := x^2y + xy^2$ under the reflection written above behave like this $$f(r(x,y)) = f(-x,-y) = -x^2y - xy^2 = -f(x,y)$$

Now we can conclude because $$\begin{split}
\iint_U f(x,y) dxdy &= \iint_{U_+} f(x,y) dxdy + \iint_{U_-} f(x,y) dxdy =\\
& =\iint_{U_+} f(x,y) dxdy + \iint_{U_+} -f(x,y) dxdy =\\
& = 0
\end{split}$$